# Is it still bad etiquette to force a link to open in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

Now tabbed browsing is the norm, is it still considered bad etiquette to force links to open in a new 'Window' (`target="_blank"`)? For a page that I am designing, I think it is by far the best option for a set of links, but I don't want to upset any purists who visit my site.

What is the polite thing to do in 2012?

Edit: The links I am talking about are to external pages.

Comment: Do you mean open in a popup? I don't know if new windows were ever "bad etiquette".

Comment: I do mean new windows. Maybe i am mistaken, but I am sure it used to be bad etiquette, back in the day where tabs didn't exist (on IE at least).

Comment: Surprised this question has been closed. It's a programming matter of best practice. Is UI not software development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most (popular) browsers have options to override how new windows / popups / tabs are handled.
There's nothing wrong with opening a link in a new tab, as long as it's not a link to your own site.

If you're linking to pages on your own site, make the link open in the same tab (So don't supply any `target`) Otherwise, people might end up with a load of tabs opened with your site, slowing their system, and generally being annoying.

Personally, I force all pages that want to open in a new window, to open in a tab instead.
Users with more "technical" experience tend to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> / <kbd>Middle-Click</kbd> to open pages in new tabs, if they want them to. Otherwise, they'll most often expect them to open in the same page.

As a rule of thumb:

*Don't force a specific sort of behaviour on your users. Make your site behave as expected.*

Comment: For us technical people, opening new tabs by ctrl + click is a no-brainier, but for many people with less tech savvy, the default behavior of the site is how they will experience it.  So I'm agreeing with you in general, but saying it may not apply if the target user base does not have a lot of experience with computers, and a new window (or tab) is really the right call.

Comment: @Nate: Good point. I usually use middle-click, but same difference, right.
I'll edit something into the answer.

Comment: Sometimes I use new tabs for spot-checking after I run a long process.  That way my site doesn't have to go through a lengthy procedure just to get back to that page. In any case, using a new window icon to let users know is nice. http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6rc5/tests/static/icons.html (ui-icon-newwin)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends upon the scenario.  I tend toward the "purist" end of this argument, but I know that Google news defaults to the new window/tab behavior.  They're not known for superb design, but given that they are a major web presence I think a case can be made for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to force them to open in a new tab, as it doesn't replace the current page with another. However, in a different context, you might want to replace the current page. In your case, I think it'll be fine, as long as you aren't using `<font face="comic_sans">` or something.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider something like lightbox. It might fit your page.
I was thinking about popup windows. But that was bad. Those are blocked by most browsers and don't work well on mobile devices.

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Or this one:
http://fancybox.net/

Comment: They wanted to know if it was bad, doing `<a href="http://www.someurl.com" target="_blank">`.

Comment: My answer shows that their are better alternatives. Which automatically means that this is not the best idea to open new window.